# PhpWord add image to table cell

Tags: php, image, phpword

I want to replace the variable (test_var) inside the document, i can create a table and add texts to it with addText, but the addImage method is not adding the image.

Here is my code:

```
$template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("test.docx");

$table = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table();

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell()->addText("test");
$table->addCell()->addImage("test.png");

$template->setComplexBlock('table_var', $table);

$template->saveAs("test_.docx");
```

- PHP version: 7.4
- PhpWord version: 0.17.0

Comment: Are you sure path is correct?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes, it's just adding an empty image.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the absolute path to the file and everything will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30510375)

Answer (score 0):

I added a new key and used it later to add the image. Worked perfectly.

```
$template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("test.docx");

$table = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table();

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell()->addText("test");
$table->addCell()->addText("${myImage}");

$template->setComplexBlock('table_var', $table);
$template->setImageValue('myImage', 'test.png');
$template->saveAs("test_.docx");
```

Good luck!